# FilterServletResponseWrapper replacement when migrating Richfaces to Primefaces. For file download

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, richfaces, wrapper

I am migrating a project from Richfaces to Primefaces and I am having problems getting file download to work again. The original uses a standard h:commandLink which tells the webflow to start the download by calling a function on the controller. The actual downloading is written to the output stream instead of being returned as a file.

Now my problem is the previous code sends a FilterServletResponseWrapper, but after changing the rich tags to prime, it now returns HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper. These wrappers are not specified anywhere and I suspect rich sends such a type internally. So if I want to specify my own wrapper to send, how could I possibly go about that? In particular I want to use Spring's ContentCachingResponseWrapper since I need to use it's .getContentInputStream() method.

P.S. I have intentionally omitted the code, because of NDA, I am hoping this is enough information to represent the problem sufficiently. If not I will be glad to clear out any questions.

Thanks

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you have switched to PrimeFaces just use the PF FileDownload which handles all this for you and if you are using JSF2.3 it uses Servlet native for the download.  See: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

Comment: Could use FileDownload, but there is a lot of internal logging and other things happening in the backend, so adding the download tag will only be a patch and it won't fit the architecture properly. We are using JSF 2.2, where can I find more information about the Servlet it uses @Melloware?

Comment: You can look at this: https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-download-file-example

Comment: Thanks, so far it seems the issue is more complex than anticipated. There is a lot of abstraction that gets in the way of simple migration and the team is cracking at it bit by bit. I believe it is fixed at this point, but now for some reason the action is triggered twice. The first time data is correctly registered and about to be returned, but then a second request comes in and wipes all previous data and does nothing on screen.